# Clearing a date picker field

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I have the below date picker field which gets populated based on a different field on the form. I need to clear this auto populated date and then click on it again and select a different date.
So, I have tried to click on the clear trigger(cross) by using Xpath. But it doesn't click. I have also tried Keys.DELETE, BACKSPACE, etc. Also, tried clear().Can anyone suggest any other ways I can achieve this using Selenium, Java or JS? I use Selenium and Java.

HTML:-

```
<div class="x-no-min-content x-datepickerfield x-pickerfield x-textfield x-field x-component x-body-align-stretch x-animate-underline x-label-align-placeholder x-label-align-vertical x-label-text-align-left null x-mandatory-field x-error-target-under x-labeled x-required x-paint-monitored x-size-monitored x-layout-auto-item" data-componentid="ext-datefield-5" data-xid="2965" id="ext-datefield-5">
<label class="x-label-el" for="ext-element-7051" id="ext-element-7053" style="width: 200px; transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px); font-size: 12px;">
    <span class="x-label-text-el" id="ext-element-7056">Delivery Date</span>
</label>
<div class="x-body-wrap-el">
    <div class="x-body-el" id="ext-element-7052">
        <div class="x-input-wrap-el">
            <div class="x-before-input-el" id="ext-element-7054"/>
            <input tabindex="0" oninput="return Ext.doEv(this, event);" class="x-input-el" type="text" id="ext-element-7051" name="delivery_date" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" data-componentid="ext-datefield-5" readonly="true">
                <div class="x-after-input-el" id="ext-element-7055">
                    *<div data-componentid="ext-cleartrigger-62" class="x-cleartrigger x-trigger x-interactive datepickerfield-cancel x-ignore-theme" data-xid="2966" id="ext-cleartrigger-62">*
                        <div class="x-icon-el x-font-icon"/>
                    </div>
                    <div data-componentid="ext-datetrigger-5" class="x-datetrigger x-trigger x-interactive" data-xid="2967" id="ext-datetrigger-5">
                        <div class="x-icon-el x-font-icon"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="x-underline-el"/>
        </div>
        <div class="x-error-el">
            <div class="x-error-icon-el x-font-icon"/>
            <div class="x-error-message-el"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="x-paint-monitor cssanimation"/>
    <div class="x-size-monitors scroll">
        <div class="expand"/>
        <div class="shrink"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Xpath used:-

```
//div[contains(@class,'x-no-min-content x-datepickerfield') and .//span[contains(text(),'Delivery Date')]]//div[contains(@class,'x-cleartrigger x-trigger')]
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Share the relevant HTML and your Xpath.

Comment: @MateMrše Updated the question with HTML and Xpath. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The Xpath looks fine, although it could be simplified.

What could be happening is that the "X" element is blocked while you are selecting a value. Try waiting for the element to be clickable:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'x-no-min-content x-datepickerfield') and .//span[contains(text(),'Delivery Date')]]//div[contains(@class,'x-cleartrigger x-trigger')]")));
```